# Does twisted arrows commute with the simplicial nerve construction?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra, simplicial-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a simplicial category, and let $N(\mathcal{C})$ be its simplicial nerve. We can form the category of twisted arrows as a simplicial category $TwArr(\mathcal{C})$

Now Lurie's Higher Algebra gives the construction of Twisted Arrows for a quasi-category, $X$, $\mathrm{TwArr}(X)$.

It is fairly clear to see that we get a map $N(TwArr(\mathcal{C}))\to \mathrm{TwArr}(N(\mathcal{C}))$. When, if ever, is this map an equivalence of quasicategories?
In Higher Algebra Lurie shows this to be true for ordinary categories, but I can't find a reference in the literature for simplicial categories.

Comment: I would be a little surprised if the answer is yes. The twisted arrow construction on the nerve has morphisms given by a 'factorization up to homotopy' whereas the other direction seems to have morphisms given by an actual factorization... Of course this doesn't rule out an equivalence of mapping spaces in the end, but still a bit fishy.

Comment: In the spirit of Dylan's comment, the simplicial mapping space in $TwArr({\cal C})$ from $Id_X: X \to X$ to $f: Y \to Z$ is the fiber of the composition map $c_{Y,X,Z}:{\rm Map}_{{\cal C}}(Y,X) \times {\rm Map}_{{\cal C}}(X,Z) \to {\rm Map}_{{\cal C}}(Y,Z)$ over the vertex $f$. This fiber will typically not be equivalent to the corresponding homotopy fiber, which is the mapping space in $TwArr(N({\cal C}))$ (at least of ${\cal C}$ is fibrant), unless we assume, for example, that $c_{Y,X,Z}$ is a Kan fibration (but this condition seems to be rarely satisfied).

Comment: Thanks for the help. That seems to answer the question for my purposes.